# Remove values in a flat indexed array if found in another flat array

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, array-difference

I would like to filter an array.

```
$a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
$b = ['c', 'd'];
```

`$a` will be filtered by values in array `$b` and the result should be:

```
['a', 'b', 'e']
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `array_diff()`;

PHP Documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 3):

```
$result = array_diff($a, $b)
```